# How to change a dictionary's key in Python using method Pop?

Tags: python, dictionary

Well, I have a dictionary that stores informations extracted from a PDF file.
Like this:

> { 'B) NAME:': 'Jair', 'H) AGE: ': ' 25', 'J) Gender': 'Male'}

I'm trying to 'clean' this dictionary by excluding the strings "b)", "h)" "j)" that came from PDF using the following code:

```
for k in mydict:
  mydict[(k.split(')')[1])] = mydict.pop(k)
```

But this code isn't working: "IndexError: list index out of range"

I cannot figure out why, cuz when I run the code with print instead the pop everything goes well:

```
for k in mydict:
        print(k.split(')')[1])
```

What should I change?

Comment: https://cito.github.io/blog/never-iterate-a-changing-dict/ .  You end up with unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add elements to or delete elements from a dictionary at the same time you are iterating through it.  You are doing both.  Your best best is to something like this:

```
new_dict = {}
for key, value in mydict.items():
    new_dict[k.split(')')[1]] = value
mydict = new_dict
```

If you're comfortable with dictionary comprehension:

```
mydict = {k.split(')')[1]: value for key, value in mydict.items()}
```

which creates a new dictionary and then assigns it to `mydict`

Comment: See comment above.  You do not iterate over an object while mutating it.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @python_learner.  The documentation pretty much says it's unpredictable.  It might do the right thing.  It might give a RunTime error.  It might fail to iterate over some items.  Because it works one a small dictionary doesn't mean it will work on a large one.  Because it works in one version of Python doesn't it will work for every version of Python.  

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views. See under `iter(dictview)`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
d = { 'B) NAME:': 'Jair', 'H) AGE: ': ' 25', 'J) Gender': 'Male'}
```

a simple regex based solution with dict comprehension (creates new dict)

```
{re.findall(".*\)\s(.*)", k)[0]: d[k] for k in d.keys()}
```

you can also use below code block (within try/except to catch runtime error) to change existing dict.

```
for k in d.keys():
    new_key = re.findall(".*\)\s(.*)", k)[0]
    d[new_key] = d[k]
    del d[k]
```